# Form validation with Jquery ans js in a seperate file

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

Hi there I am really stuck on this one.

Is there someone who knows how to write the following jQuery form validation? I am sure that it is very simple, but I can not figure this one out to save my life.

Thank you for you sharing your knowledge.

I need to write WITH jquery the following form validation. Whenever an error is encountered, prevent the form from being submitted. There are 4 inputs which get validated by the jquery code. Also I ma not allowed to link to my own jQuery file. I ma not sure, but I think this jQuery from validation link is broken.

Validation Rules are as follow:

- INPUT: Username; Required (yes); Validation (Must be 5-10 characters long).
- INPUT: Email; Required (yes); Validation (Must have an @ sign, must have a period).
- INPUT: Street name; Required (no); Validation (Must start with a number).
- INPUT: Year of birth; Required (yes); Validation (must be numeric).

My code looks as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<!-- Hi JASON YOUR PLUGIN DDOE SNOT WORK!!! I used another plugin from the jquery site.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form1").validate({

        rules: {
            name:  {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
                maxlength: 10
            },
            address:  {
                number: true,
            },
            email: {// compound rule 
                required: true, 
                email: true 
            }
        },

        url: {
            url: true
        },

        messages: {
            name: {
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required.")
            }
        },

        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);

            setTimeout(function() {

                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);

            }, 1000);

        }

    });

});


  </script> 



</head>
<body>


    <form id="form1" method="post" action=""> 
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Username *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Email address </span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Street address *</span><input type="text" name="address" /></div>
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Year of birth</span><input type="text" name="date" /></div> 

      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Thank you for you sharing your knowledge._ ...why this appear many times..

Comment: The `url:` clause should be inside the `rules:` option. But there's no URL field in the form, so it should just be left out entirely.

Comment: The URL I use for jquery-validate is http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Your title mentions having things in separate files, but the question doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

- was missing a comma between two rules on your `name` field.
- was improperly using the `url` rule by having it *outside* of `rules: {}`.  Since I see nothing in your form requiring such a rule, I just removed it.
- seems to be missing the plugin entirely.  You need to actually "include" the jQuery Validate plugin someplace *after* you include jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Otherwise, your code, as you presented it, is working now:  http://jsfiddle.net/4FGmx/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            address: {
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required.")
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

});
```

---

As per your rule specifications, you can do the following.  Notice usage of the `rangelength` rule instead of using `minlength` and `maxlength`.  [See documentation for all available rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

If you want your `address` field to only *"start with a number"*, then you'll need to remove the `number` rule and write your own custom regex function and incorporate it using [the `addMethod` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/4FGmx/1/**

```
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [5,10]
        },
        address: {
            mycustomrule: true
        },
        email: { 
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        date: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    },
```